# JQuery check if div display flex and set body overflow to hiden

Tags: jquery

I have a popup that I want to check in an interval. Once it's CSS `display` is set to `flex`/ or `block`, the `overflow` of the `body` should be set to `hidden` because I don't want to be able to scroll as it's a long form.

```js
function checkPopup() {
  if ($(".bdp-poup").css("display", "flex")) {
    $('.body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('.body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  }
}

setInterval(checkPopup, 1000);
```

Comment: It would be more like `if ($(".bdp-poup").css("display") == "flex")`

Comment: 1) Use the getter of `css()`, not the setter, in your `if` condition 2) Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect the element being displayed, not an interval.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine 2 functions:

1. Saves the element display property state, then on some interval, check whether this property is changed
2. Check if the element property is displayed flex or none and call this function into the first one.

```js
var myElement = $(".bdp-poup");
var originalDisplay = myElement.css("display");

// Check for changes to the display property
setInterval(function() {
  if (myElement.is(":visible") && myElement.css("display") !== originalDisplay) {
    console.log("Display property has changed to " + myElement.css("display"));
    checkVisibility();
    originalDisplay = myElement.css("display");
  }
}, 100);
  
// Check if display flex or none
function checkVisibility() {
  if (myElement.css("display") == "flex") {
    // Element has display: flex
  } else if (myElement.css("display") == "none") {
    // Element has display: none
  } else {
    // Element has a different display value
  }
}
```

```css
.bdp-poup {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bdp-poup">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```